# How to insert text at an angle? 

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to insert text into blackberry at an 90 degrees angle. I need to surround image with text (see picture):

[image]

How to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: do you use Graphics or Graphics2D to draw your text?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far that isn't working.

Comment: @stas, how to do it with Graphics? could you give example? thanks

Comment: @Kane, it isn't working because i don't know how to do it, because i don't find such code as g.Rotate() in Graphics. So how to do it? Example anyone? thanks

Comment: unfair discrimination of less experienced community members ;p

Comment: From the mouse-over text on the downvote arrow "**This question does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: @ShouldO To avoid having your question down voted try updating it to include the research you have done and/or the code you have tried. Also, if someone provides an answer which solves your problem click 'Accept'. It is frustrating for responders when their answer goes unaccepted despite solving the problem originally posted.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    //Render horizontal text and image;

    //Render vertical text;        
    g.drawImage(getRotatedText(text), x, y, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
}

public Image getRotatedText(String text) {

    int width = //horizontal text width considering the current font
    int height = //horizontal text font height

    final Image img = Image.createImage(width, height);
    Graphics gx = img.getGraphics();
    gx.drawString(text, 0, 0, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
    gx = null;

    int[] rowData = new int[width];
    int[] rotatedData = new int[width * height];

    int rotatedIndex = 90;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        img.getRGB(rowData, 0, width, 0, i, width, 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            rotatedIndex = angle == 90 ? (height - i - 1) + j * height
                    : (angle == 270 ? i + height * (width - j - 1)
                    : width * height - (i * width + j) - 1);
            rotatedData[rotatedIndex] = rowData[j];
        }
    }

    if (angle == 90 || angle == 270) {
        return Image.createRGBImage(rotatedData, height, width, true);
    } else {
        return Image.createRGBImage(rotatedData, width, height, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShoulO, was this answer helpful for your question, if so accept it to help future readers of this post.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I initially hoped that there is some simple way to do it which i overlooked sort of g.Rotate(90), your code is a bit complicated , I'll see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to target OS6+ then [Graphics.drawTextOnPath(...)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#drawTextOnPath%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawTextParam,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.TextMetrics%29) is what you want.